# Almacenar nombre y ruta de archivo subido en php

Tags: php

Señores un saludo cordial para todos.

Tengo un script para subir archivos a una carpeta en el servidor con php, inicialmente tengo el formulario que captura el archivo. Si le incluyo otra información al formulario, cómo podría almacenar el nombre y ruta del archivo en mysql y como podría recuperarlo después en un listado?, para subir archivos pdf.

Les agradezco ejemplos concretos para poder entender como funciona.

ARCHIVO 1: FORMULARIO HTML

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
   <h2>SUBIR ARCHIVOS</h2>      
   <input type="file" name="file">      
   <input type="submit" name="" value="Subir archivo">  
</form>
```

ARCHIVO 2: SCRIPT EN PHP

```
    <?php  

    $directorio = "subidas/"; $archivo = $directorio . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
    $tipoArchivo = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));  
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"], $archivo)) {
        echo "archivo subido con exito";    
     } else {
        echo "error en la subida del archivo";
    }

    ?>
```

---

un saludo cordial sr_luis

Intente con el codigo pero me sale un error, mira:

Archivo 1: INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>SUBIR ARCHIVOS</h2>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Subir archivo">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

ARCHIVO 2: Upload.php

```
<?php  

$directorio = "subidas/";

$archivo = $directorio . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$tipoArchivo = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"], $archivo)) {
        echo "archivo subido con exito";

    } else {
        echo "error en la subida del archivo";
    }

    require("conexion.php");

    $nombre = $_POST['file'];
    $ruta = "subidas/";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO archivos (nombre_archivo, ruta_subida) VALUES ('$nombre','$ruta')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

              if ($consulta==false) {
            echo "Error en la consulta";

          } else {


            echo "Datos almacenados exitosamente<br><br>";

          }

          mysqli_close($conexion);



?>
```

El archivo de conexion esta bueno, pues efectivamente se conecta y me almacena la ruta, pero no me esta almacenando el nombre del archivo.

El error que me sale es:
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\subir-archivos\upload.php on line 18

Comment: Que pena, no se lee el segundo bloque de php:

<?php  

$directorio = "subidas/";

$archivo = $directorio . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$tipoArchivo = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"], $archivo)) {
  echo "archivo subido con exito";

 } else {
  echo "error en la subida del archivo";
 }

?>

Comment: Perdona, pero a que ruta de subida te refieres? (Supongo que la ruta donde subes el archivo al servidor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la extructura de la tabla de mysql tuviese como campos nombre_archivo y ruta_subida:

```
$nombre = $_POST['file'];
$ruta = "subidas/";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contrasenya, $bd);
$sql = "INSERT INTO archivos (nombre_archivo, ruta_subida) VALUES ('$nombre', '$ruta')";
$consulta = mysql_query($sql, $conexion);
```

> Estas líneas añaden a una tabla sql los datos del archivo y la ruta.

Para recuperar la lista de los archivos y su ruta:

```
$nombre = "nombre del archivo";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contrasenya, $bd);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM archivos WHERE nombre_archivo == '$nombre'";
$consulta = mysql_query($sql, $conexion);
$fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);
while($fila) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>{$fila["nombre_archivo"]}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$fila["ruta_subida"]}</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);
}
```

Comment: Te respondo en otro texto pues aca no me cabe.

Comment: no @JuanCarlosMonsalve dale editar a tu pregunta y ahi agrega todo lo que le vayas a mencionar

Comment: Ya lo arregle, coloque  $nombre = $archivo; y me guarda la ruta y el nombre en el mismo campo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMonsalve Me alegra saber que te pude ayudar en tú problema. :)

Comment: Y gracias por contestar y mostrar una corrección (aunque lamentablemente no pude verla por que el sistema no me lo notifica, o tiene esa función y no la conozco), la acabo de marcar como **respuesta útil** por que estoy seguro que le servirá al siguiente usuario que tenga un problema similar, no borraré está respuesta por que me parece que las 2 respuesta se complementan y si se borrá una el usuario final a lo mejor se siente un poco desconcertado.